# FindAsync with non-primary key value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, entity-framework-6

```
public class Foo
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

This appears to be the way to do this asynchronously:

```
DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
Foo foo = await db.Foos.FindAsync(fooid);
```

How does one asynchronously get all of the Foos for a specific user based on UserId's value?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Assuming you are using Entity Framework 6.0 (prerelease):

```
var userId = ...;
var foos = await db.Foos.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: tip: If you're missing ToListAsync() then add using System.Data.Entity;

Comment: Any way to do this lazily?

Comment: @Sinjai: If you mean loading entity properties lazily, then no. EF doesn't support asynchronous lazy loading.

Comment: @StephenCleary Doesn't code like that become a problem, then, when the database reaches a certain size?

Comment: @Sinjai: If you use eager loading for relations you know you'll need, and explicit queries for relations you may or may not need, then it's exactly as efficient database-wise as lazy-loaded relations. I recommend asking your own question if this isn't clear.