# SaveChanges only works in debug

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a MVC controller method that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Edit(Foo input)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Foo current = await db.foos.FindAsync(input.Id);
        current.SomeProp = input.SomeProp; // etc.
        db.Entry(current).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This works when I'm debugging in Visual Studio. When I'm not debugging, I get a 500. **What difference would debugging make here?**

Note: I'm not using `db.Entry(current).CurrentValues.SetValues(input);` because there are some properties of `Foo` I don't want to change here.

Edit: I can't figure out how to get the exception details when not in debug mode.  I tried writing it to a file. This works in debug mode (with `throw new Exception("test");` taking the place of the statement that only works in debug mode) but I get a 401 when not debugging.  The IIS user does have write permission on the directory.

Comment: What's the details of the error?  a 500 error is way to general to debug.

Comment: response of 500 = server error = your code had an unhandled exception. Add some logging, use windebug, or do something else to figure out what the exception was. There are many ways to get the exception and its details (type, stack trace, inner exception, etc).

Comment: @Igor Believe me, I tried that. After several hours of searching, I've been unable to find any way to get the exception when not in debug mode.

Comment: @ErikPhilips See my edit.

Comment: Use [ELMAH](https://elmah.github.io/) to log the exception. It's the de facto standard for this kind of stuff.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the state of the entity yourself unless you've turned off tracking completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception was a `DbEntityValidationException` indicating that a required field was missing. The missing field is a relation of `Foo`.

Based on [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx), I believe my code loads `Foo`'s relations lazily. I didn't even consider this possibility because I misunderstood comments like ["EF doesn't support asynchronous lazy loading."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964488/findasync-with-non-primary-key-value#comment80646874_18964956) Inspecting the object in debug mode seemed to confirm that its relations were being loaded eagerly. But now I realize that inspecting the object may have triggered lazy loading!